# Updates for different user on work mac

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, user-account, ilife

My office is the only one in my place of business that uses macs (I guess I just lucked out with a boss who insisted on macs), so I.T. has no idea what to do for this situation.

The person who I replaced used her personal account on the app store. There are updates for built-in apps such as iPhoto, iMovie, etc. for which I keep getting reminders. I can't hide the updates because I can't log into her account. Likewise, I can't install those updates.

Any idea how to either allow me to install the updates or hide the reminders?

Comment: Are you using your own profile on that Mac? Or are you logged in the same account as the person who left? Does the company have an iTunes account you can log into?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, I uninstalled them and reinstalled which didn't really matter as they were all free apps.

Answer (score 0):

You have three options and can choose a different option for each of the offending apps:

1. Delete the app and go without it.
2. Delete the app and get an account you control to install it.
3. [Opt out of updates by modifying the package contents](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69821/how-can-i-opt-out-of-updates-for-one-app-when-using-the-app-store) - remove the Mac App Store receipt folder so that the app store no longer thinks you installed it from the app store.

Be sure you make a good backup (and perhaps test restoring that backup) before proceeding - especially with the third option in case that hack no longer works.